# php associative array error

Tags: arrays, associative

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here because it is giving me a blank result. just a newbie wanting to learn.

```
$months = "2";
$month = array(1=>January,"2"=>February,"3"=>March,"4"=>April,"5"=>May,"6"=>June,"7"=>July,"8"=>August,"9"=>September,"10"=>October,"11"=>November,"12"=>December);
$description = 'In respect of '.$particular.' collection for the month of ';print  $month['$months'];

echo $description
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't enclosed the array string values in quotes. Change your $month definition to this:

```
$month = array(
     1 => "January",
     2 => "February",
     3 => "March",
     4 => "April",
     5 => "May",
     6 => "June",
     7 => "July",
     8 => "August",
     9 => "September",
    10 => "October",
    11 => "November",
    12 => "December"
);
```

Also, you don't really need to create an associative array for the month names. You can get a month's name from its number like this:

```
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
```